# Store checkbox selections into MySQL database table using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, checkbox, pdo

I have a list of optional clothing items as checkboxes, there may be a greater number than the 5 below.

```
shoes, pants, skirt, socks, jacket //list of possible choices
```

A comma-separated array is created in jquery of the chosen item. Let's say the following are chosen:

```
shoes, socks, jacket //array posted as $_POST['clothes']
```

In the db, each customer has these options in the clothes table with 'yes' or 'no' under the clothing items. However, the clothing item are named a bit differently but map out to the same options:

'clothes' table before insert

```
customer_id  dress_shoes  elegant_pants  long_skirt  ankle_socks  biker_jacket
     1            no            yes           no           no           no
```

With the $_POST['clothes'], I'm trying to loop through the array, updating the corresponding fields to `yes`, and the non corresponding fields to `no` in the db. I'm having a hard time doing that.

'clothes' table after insert

```
customer_id  dress_shoes  elegant_pants  long_skirt  ankle_socks  biker_jacket
     1            yes            no           no          yes          yes
```

I tried using `array_intersect()` to get the items to mark as 'yes':

```
$clothesArray = array("shoes", "socks", "jacket"); // Posted clothes
$clothesArrayAll = array("shoes", "pants", "skirt", "socks", "jacket"); // All clothes
$common = array_intersect($clothesArrayAll,$clothesArray);
print_r($common);
Array ( [0] => shoes [3] => socks [4] => jacket )
```

I'm trying to somehow loop through the `$clothesArrayAll`, give a 'yes' to common clothes, and a 'no' to all others in the array. Then, I'm trying to update the 'clothes' table via PDO, setting each corresponding field to a 'yes' or 'no' in the most efficient way. I'm stuck after getting the common clothes array above and not sure how to proceed.

Comment: So is it the SQL you're having a hard time with then? You're going to need a way to map the names of the columns between your PHP and the actual database.

Comment: @TMan is bang on - is there a specific reason that the names between PHP and SQL don't match up?

Comment: @TMan It's the mapping the $clothesArrayAll to the columns in the DB, and the SQL to submit them efficiently. I'm thinking there may be a way in php to map them, maybe playing around with arrays, not sure.

Comment: @endyourif The reason is because I'm trying to find common elements with a php array that matches the html elements (don't want to put the actual table names there for security), so I need to figure out a way to do the mapping (I can always update the php array manually to match the db fields, but need a way to map them for inserting them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track.  I would just add one additional array that contains the mappings of your fields, e.g.

```
$mappingArray = array('shoes' => 'dress_shoes', 'socks' => 'ankle_socks', ...);
```

With this array and the previous you can loop through and set your SQL accordingly based on the value of the `$common` field with the key in the `$mappingArray`

Edit with example (probably not the most optimized):

```
$finalArray = array();

foreach ($mappingArray as $key => $value) {
   $finalArray[$value] = in_array($key, $common) ? 'yes' : 'no';
}
```

`$finalArray` will now have an yes/no statement for each value that matches your db table.

Edit to include PDO:  I would actually update the above loop as follows:

```
$finalArray = array();
$sql = "INSERT INTO cloths (" . implode(",", array_values($mappingArray)) . ") VALUES (:" . implode(",:", array_values($mappingArray)) . ")";;
foreach ($mappingArray as $key => $value) {
    $finalArray[":" . $value] = in_array($key, $common) ? 'yes' : 'no';
}

$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute($finalArray);
```

Going on the fly with this one, so something like that...

Comment: Do you mind expanding on the last sentence by showing an example?

Comment: thanks for the correction, i hate that i get redirected to a new page to edit because i couldn't see the original code anymore :(

Comment: No worries, almost there:) $finalArray maps out great, left with the PDO update though. Any idea how to insert it?

Comment: See if that above edit works, as mentioned, typing on-the-fly, so hopefully no typos.

Comment: Okay, so there is a typo in the table name but it won't let me fix it because it's less than 6 chars. However, this works for inserting a new customer perfectly, not updating a current one. It would be nice to have it update a current customer, but you've helped out so much that I am accepting your answer as is. Thanks for all your help and pretty smart for on the fly:) I'll try and figure out the update part:)

Comment: Check out INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not change your HTML field names to match your database names, set a default of 'no' in the atabase then...

```
$cols='INSERT INTO clothes ';
$values=' VALUES ';

$join='(';
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$val) {
    $cols.=$join . $key;
    $values=$join . ':' . $key;
    $join=',';
}
$qry=$cols . ')' . $values . ')';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($qry);
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$val) {
    $stmt->bindParam(':' . $key, $_POST[$key]);
}
```

But you might want to check the posted names are valid column names - you can get the column names and types from the table using

```
DESC clothes;
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using the db names in the html form, and instead map them in php for security purposes. Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Why do you think that should help with security? You've got a lot more things to worry about on that front, particularly if you think mapping an array to an insert is difficult.

Answer (score 0):

The first priority is to validate the submission payload.  You probably want to make sure that the customer_id is a positive integer and that the clothes items match a whitelist of possibilities.

Because the whitelist is required, it can serve a second purpose of storin the default values.

Follow the preparatory steps below to sanitize and standardize the input data before constructing PDO query.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/mujhD))

```
$defaults = [
    "shoes" => 'no',
    "pants" => 'no',
    "skirt" => 'no',
    "socks" => 'no',
    "jacket" => 'no',
];

$_POST['id'] = '2';
$_POST['clothes'] = "shoes, socks, jacket";
$ticked = array_fill_keys(explode(', ', $_POST['clothes']), 'yes');
$yesses = array_intersect_key($ticked, $defaults);
$row = ['id' => (int) $_POST['id']] + array_replace($defaults, $yesses);
```

From here, it is unclear if you mean to INSERT or UPDATE a row.  If updating, then a primary key value should be passed with the submission data to determine the row to modify.

Code: ([PHPize Demo](https://phpize.online/s/b4))

```
$sql = sprintf(
    'INSERT INTO clothes
    (customer_id, dress_shoes, elegant_pants, long_skirt, ankle_socks, biker_jacket)
    VALUES (%s)',
    implode(',', array_fill(0, count($row), '?'))
);
($pdo->prepare($sql))->execute(array_values($row));
```

If updating the row, then adjust the query but use the submission data in virtually the same way. ([PHPize Demo](https://phpize.online/s/j4))

```
$_POST['id'] = '1';
$_POST['clothes'] = "shoes, socks, jacket";
$ticked = array_fill_keys(explode(', ', $_POST['clothes']), 'yes');
$yesses = array_intersect_key($ticked, $defaults);
$row = ['id' => (int) $_POST['id']] + array_replace($defaults, $yesses);
//var_export($row);

$sql = <<<SQL
    UPDATE clothes
    SET dress_shoes = :shoes,
        elegant_pants = :pants,
        long_skirt = :skirt,
        ankle_socks = :socks,
        biker_jacket = :jacket
    WHERE customer_id = :id
SQL;
($pdo->prepare($sql))->execute($row);
```